# Giving an example to the following statement regarding set theory.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Write down in roster notation a set  of cardinality 3, of which all elements are sets, and which
satisfies the following property:
∀,  ∈  ( ⊆  ⇒  ⊆ ).
No justification is needed. Do not use ellipses (“…”) in your answer.

What I understands from this question is that all the 3 sets have to be the same to fulfill the statement.Example of an answer would be { {1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}} am i right?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and also show the work you have done so far.

Comment: OP has substantially changed the question after I posted my answer.  I believe my answer to the original question is a very strong hint to the answer to this one.  The change convinces me that OP has not understood what I was saying.

Answer (score 1):

$U$ is a set of sets.  The inner sets have to have three members each but nothing is specified about the size of $U$.  Your example has two problems.  First, the elements of a set have to be distinct.  Second, you need a set of outer braces for the set.

It turns out any set of sets of cardinality three  where the sets are disjoint works.  For any finite sets $A,B$ of the same size $A \subseteq B \implies B \subseteq A$.  This is because the only way one finite set can be a subset of another finite set of the same size is for the two sets to be equal.

The simplest $U$ that satisfies the requirement is the empty set.  Since there are no sets that are elements of $U$ the requirement is vacuously satisfied.

Comment: sorry i think i think i phrased the wrong question wrongly. It should be Write down in roster notation a set  of cardinality 3, of which all elements are sets, and which
satisfies the following property as the heading. In this case what should the answer be sorry I am new to set theory.

Comment: My amended answer says that any $U$ composed of disjoint sets of size $3$ satisfies the requirement.  So $\{\{1,2,3\}\}$ or (if that offends you because $A$ and $B$ must be the same) you can use $\{\{1,2,3\},\{4,5,6\}\}$.  I think it is important to understand my trivial examples.

Comment: I have ammended my question as set U has to be of cardiannlity 3, of which all elements are sets.

Comment: That is wildly different from the original question.  If you understand my answer to the original, you will know how to answer this version.

Comment: I dont really understand so in this case is my originial answer correct.

Comment: It depends on whether your class considers a set with three identical elements acceptable, with it being equivalent to a set with just one of them, or completely unacceptable.  This is an edge case where definitions will differ.  I think the majority would say it was acceptable, so your answer would be equivalent to $\{\{1,2,3\}\}$ and acceptable.  If you just want credit for the problem you are done.  If you want to understand the material you are not.

Answer (score 0):

An example could be $U=\{\{1\}, \{2,3\}, \{4,5,6\}\}$.

It has three elements, all three are sets. And there is no inclusion relation between any of them. So it’s voidly true that **if** one is a subset of the other, the reverse also holds, as your property states. Otherwise put, there is no counterexample among them so the statement holds.

The element sets could have been any size.

Comment: OP changed the requirement that the elements of $U$ be size $3$ to $U$ being of size $3$.  Your answer is correct to the new problem.

Comment: @RossMillikan I only saw that latter version I believe. And feel free to edit such obvious typos. I just fix them when I see them. That’s in the spirit of this site I believe.

Comment: I got my hand slapped by someone who didn't like me editing their posts, so I leave comments instead.